# HDFS Error while copying the file : Could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

While copying file from Local system to HDFS i am getting the below error,I am using Single Node

13/08/04 10:50:02 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: java.io.IOException: File /user/vishu/input could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

I deleted the dfs/Name and dfs/data directories and formated the Namenode still No use.
and I have enough space to replicate the Data.

Could anyone help resolving this issue?

Regards,
Vishwa

Answer (score 6):

Some times the data node may be starting up slowly and this may cause the above issue.. keep some wait time after the start of dfs and mapred demons.

bin/hadoop namenode -format

bin/start-dfs.sh

wait for some 5 min(data node will be up in the time)

bin/start-mapred.sh

Comment: This worked Fine for me . I never Knew waiting will solve my Problem.Thanks for lot

Comment: @Vishwa, if your problem was solved by above answer. Plese accept it as answer. It will help other users facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all daemons are started or not. make sure that your input file is correct.

Use the following command to copy the file from local to hdfs:

```
bin/hadoop fs -mkdir abc

bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal inputfile abc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Client writing the file is outside the cluster, make sure the client has access to the Datanode.

Look at this http://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes/